# homebrew python upgrade breaks installed python tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, homebrew

I use Homebrew and pip to manage my Python installation. A recent `brew upgrade` seems to have broken the Python shell commands such as `pip`, `ipython` and `jupyter`.

```
 !  ~/ jupyter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Sat Oct 27 14:06:46 2018
Failed to execute process '/usr/local/bin/jupyter'. Reason:
The file '/usr/local/bin/jupyter' specified the interpreter '/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6', which is not an executable command.
```

Furthermore, the `brew upgrade` was supposed to upgrade to Python 3.7, which is now on the system, but the command `python3` still points to 3.6.

My instinct is to start over with a clean install of everything Python. Can you suggest a way to do this (especially now that `pip` is broken)?

`brew reinstall jupyter` does not fix this, and produces:

```
==> Installing jupyter
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/jupyter-1.0.0_5.high_sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/35/357e40d51326385dda5eed4cef3fbb3640d3955ba8010145ca45459529231114?__gda__=exp=1540644375~hmac=049a5af67ac32cab5a66ad1346299fae0f82d746bd3e9b447d9a21a268e96ad0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22jupyter-1.0.0_5.high_sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz%22&response-content-type=application%2Fgzip&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX1_OrYeCyc0sGgKRw0sOPJEjC3dAXrj6v6YoPm3azxR3Et6paTgqR
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring jupyter-1.0.0_5.high_sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/jupyter
Target /usr/local/bin/jupyter
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/jupyter'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite jupyter

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run jupyter

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-console
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-kernel
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-kernelspec
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-migrate
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-nbconvert
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-run
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-troubleshoot
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-trust
```

Comment: While in general, I don't consider brewed python suitable for development or local scripting, this may be not as bad as you think. How did you install `jupyter`, did you also brew it? A simple reinstall may be already sufficient: `brew reinstall jupyter ipython` etc.

Comment: It certainly looks bad ;) See my edits

Comment: I think i did not install `jupyter` via `brew` but via `pip`. Not sure though.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I would probably first revert to Python 3.6, freeze the packages list, uninstall them, then install Python 3.7 and install packages from list: `brew remove python3 && brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb && pip3.6 list --format=freeze > reqs.txt && pip3.6 uninstall -r reqs.txt && brew remove python3 && brew install python3`. Now you have a Python 3.7 installation, but without any packages that you have installed with 3.6.

Comment: How to uninstall packages cleanly when pip is broken?

Comment: It should be repaired once you bring python 3.6 back.

Comment: Once you have the clean installation of Python 3.7, you can reinstall the packages for 3.7 with `pip3.7 install -r reqs.txt`.

Comment: `~/ brew remove python3                                                                                                                       
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... (3,997 files, 122.9MB)
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5`

Comment: `brew remove python3 --force` should do; otherwise check whether `brew doctor` has something useful.

Comment: In the end there was no way to remove python with homebrew without some manual chmod and sudo rm... This worked though and after this ordeal I switched to Anaconda Python.

Comment: Wise choice. I'm rarely using conda besides working with PyTorch, instead relying on the ecosystem around the vanilla Python installations from https://python.org/downloads, but conda is miles better than brewed Python from my experience.